# Brunch Installing on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ubuntu, coffeescript, brunch

I was going to use brunch to complile coffescript and less on ubuntu
    command : npm install brunch -b
    And I have some issues like following when install it.

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm ERR! error installing brunch@1.6.7
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: coffee-script@'>=1.6.2- <1.7.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.7.0","0.7.1","0.7.2","0.9.0","0.9.1","0.9.2","0.9.3","0.9.4","0.9.5","0.9.6","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.2.0","1.3.0","1.3.1","1.3.2","1.3.3","1.4.0","1.5.0","1.6.0","1.6.1"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/administrator/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "brunch" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/administrator
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: coffee-script@'>=1.6.2- <1.7.0-'
npm ERR! message Valid install targets:
npm ERR! message ["0.7.0","0.7.1","0.7.2","0.9.0","0.9.1","0.9.2","0.9.3","0.9.4","0.9.5","0.9.6","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.2.0","1.3.0","1.3.1","1.3.2","1.3.3","1.4.0","1.5.0","1.6.0","1.6.1"]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/administrator/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Your node installations seems too old. Try upgrading it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per DrColossos try updating node...

```
# update node
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs

# now brunch
sudo npm install -g brunch
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating to the latest npm you can also try installing the latest version of brunch :

```
git clone https://github.com/brunch/brunch.git
cd brunch 
sudo npm install . -g
```

Now that you have the latest brunch get the latest skeleton and dependencies:

```
brunch new <name> --skeleton https://github.com/paulmillr/brch-with-chaplin.git
cd <name>
bower install
```

Ta